# Sql query only printing first row

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am coding in php and the code takes data from an array to fetch additional data from a mysql db. Because I need data from two different tables, I use nested while loops. But the code below always only prints out (echo "a: " . $data3[2]; or echo "b: " . $data3[2];) one time:

```
foreach($stuff as $key)
{
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE id='$key'";
    $result3 = MySQL_query($query3, $link_id);

    while ($data3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
    {
        $query4 = "SELECT * FROM foobar_img WHERE id='$data3[0]'";
        $result4 = MySQL_query($query4, $link_id);

        while ($data4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
        {   
            $x += 1;
            if ($x % 3 == 0)
            {
                echo "a: " . $data3[2];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "b: " . $data3[2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sure looks like a prime candidate for sql injection.  Tsk. Tsk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, improve your SQL:

```
SELECT
    img.*
FROM
    foobar foo
    INNER JOIN foobar_img img ON
        foo.id = img.id
WHERE
    foo.id = $key
```

You will only have to iterate through one array.

Also, it appears that you're actually only selecting one row, so spitting out one row is expected behavior.

Additionally, please prevent yourself from SQL injection by using [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE id='" . 
     mysql_real_escape_string($key) . "'";
```

**Update**: As Dan as intimated, please run this query in your MySQL console to get the result set back, so you know what you're playing with. When you limit the query to one ID, you're probably only pulling back one row. That being said, I have no idea how many $keys are in $stuff, but if it spins over once, then it will be one.

You may be better off iterating through $stuff and building out an IN clause for your SQL:

```
$key_array = "";
foreach($stuff as $key)
{
    $key_array .= ",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($key) . "'";
}
$key_array = substr($key_array, 1);
```

...

```
WHERE foo.id IN ($key_array)
```

This will give you a result set with your complete list back, instead of sending a bunch of SELECT queries to the DB. Be kind to your DB and please use set-based operations when possible. MySQL will appreciate it.

I will also point out that it appears as if you're using text primary keys. Integer, incremental keys work best as PK's, and I highly suggest you use them!

Comment: Just to make it a bit more clear, "SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE id='$key'" only selects the rows with whatever $key is set to

Comment: I need to use data from both tables! Your example works but I can't access data from foo using it, can I?

Comment: @Hadorkugh: You very much need to get familiar with SQL if you intend on using it in your apps. This is what's called an inner join, which combines the results of two tables, and it is phenomenally common. The power of SQL is its ability to join and operate on sets of data very efficiently. You need to start thinking in a set-based way before you can grok SQL. See this site for tutorials to help you learn a bit about SQL: http://sqlcourse.com/intro.html

Comment: Yes, I need to read up on sql. But right now I need to press on, meet deadlines, and deliver.

Comment: @Hadorkugh: Then you're at the mercy of the internet. Above is the code you need to get over this hurdle. Please review it and understand it at some point, as it's chuck full of important and fundamental concepts to web development.

Comment: Ok, I've been able to join tables and most work with the exception of this: when I've fetched the sql data I need to access $data[4] which contains table from the table foobar_img ("FROM foobar INNER JOIN foobar_img"). $data[4] should contain data from the column foobar_img.url, but it returns empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a JOIN between these two tables.  It the correct way to use SQL, and it will work much faster.  Doing an extra query inside the loop is bad practice, like putting *loop-invariant code* inside a loop.